# How to find date difference for specific date format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript) but this is not working for my case as my dates are in a specific format "yyyy-MM-dd" i.e. "2014-08-29" and "2014-08-31".
I tried below but not working as expected. **"dtpEffectiveFrom"** & **"dtpEffectiveTo"** both are HTML5 **date** field. For the above date range, output is showing NaN days instead of 3 days.

```
var effectiveFrom = $("#dtpEffectiveFrom").val();
var effectiveTo = $("#dtpEffectiveTo").val();

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return (second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}

var msg = "Are you applying for a " + daydiff(effectiveFrom, effectiveTo) + " day(s) leave?";
alert(msg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this code. You need to convert string to date and use getTime function to get dates in milli seconds.

```
var effectiveFrom = "2014-08-29";
var effectiveTo = "2014-09-31";

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return (second.getTime() - first.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + 1;
}

var days = daydiff(new Date(effectiveFrom), new Date(effectiveTo));

console.log(days);
```

Comment: I tried your code, but this is showing difference of 2 days, but i need the result to include from date too, as I am expecting the result to display 3 days as output. Can you do something about it? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to include from date then add 1 into result as 31 - 29 will always be 2. See modified code

Answer (score 1):

Try using daydiff function like this:

```
function daydiff(first, second) {
    first=new Date(first);
    second=new Date(second);
    return (second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date object to handle the format...

```
    var effectiveFrom = new Date($("#dtpEffectiveFrom").val());
    var effectiveTo = new Date($("#dtpEffectiveTo").val());

    function daydiff(first, second) {
        return (second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }

    var msg = "Are you applying for a " + daydiff(effectiveFrom, effectiveTo) + " day(s) leave?";
    alert(msg);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/crt2a6xz/